# zip selected directories recursively in linux

Tags: linux, backup, unix, zip

I would like to **zip** only selected directories(and its child directories as well)

I have many directories in the current folder like app, content, db, library etc.

But I would like the zip only app and content and its child folders. I am trying the following.

```
zip -r ../backups/code/20110625 -i app/* -i content/* . *
```

But I am getting the following error.

> zip error: Invalid command arguments (nothing to select from)

What is the correct syntax to achieve this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
zip -r myzipfile.zip ../backups/code/20110625 app/* content/* . *
```

You need to put the name of the zipfile first.

Comment: Thanks. I need to remove the leading slash from app and content to make it work.

Comment: @emaillenin No probs. I made the change, even though it is context specific. Will you accept the answer please? Glad it worked for you.